# List all friends which a user is also following using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

As a personal utility, I'm trying to write a short script (preferably in python but essentially I'm looking for the proper REST calls) to get a list of all my friends who I am also following (actually, list all friends and for each one see whether I am also following them).

I tried playing with the API but:

- Could not get the pagination right. There seems to be a link to the next results "page", but when I follow this link, the next page is always empty. I do realize this is mainly do to my incompetence with this API, but I just didn't think it would be so difficult.
- When I view a specific friend's connection to my user, I can't seem to find this information. This data is obviously stored somewhere, as it is available using standard methods (i.e, open up a friend's facebook page in the browser and look for the "Following" part)

This may sound like a silly question and I did try playing around with the graph explorer, after generating a token with all possible permissions, but I did not get far.

Please help me make my life a little easier by not having to resort to the manual way of opening up every single friend page, this sounds exhausting.

PS: This may sound like a personal question and not very professional, but as I was struggling with this task, I though it may be of use to other individuals looking for this functionality

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing all friends isn't possible with v2.0 API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/

As long as you have an application that can still run v1.0 API calls then you can do an FQL call

`SELECT is_following, target_id FROM connection WHERE source_id=me() AND target_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())`

Comment: Thanks for link. Now I understand why pagination didn't work :/ it only showed me friends using the "Graph Explorer" app.

Comment: @dankilman Well by default the Explorer runs 2.0 you will have to switch it to 1.0

Comment: The documentation states that for sessions generated after april 2014, requests to 1.0 will be redirected to 2.0 anyway. I also tested this and switched to 1.0 and got the same result

Comment: Which is what I said. I said the Explorer tool defaults to 2.0 initially. You still need an that can still run 1.0. In the future that is by Dec 2014 this call will not work with any app.